# In Rails, should I use the generators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

I've encountered information that implies most experienced Rails developers don't use scaffolding. Do most experienced Rails developers even use the generators for Models, Controllers, and Migrations?

For example, as a seasoned Rails developer would I do:

```
rails g model Post name title content
```

or

```
rails g migration Create_Posts
```

and then modify it with:

```
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :title
    t.text :content

    t.timestamps
  end
```

and also manually create post.rb

Is using generators a best practice within Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never use the generators.  I find that I just end up deleting half the stuff they create until I ultimately need to add those files/methods.  In a decent text editor, it takes no time at all to create a new controller, a new model, a new template, a new spec etc.

One exception, however, is the migration generator.  It's easier to use the generator in this case, since the migration has to be versioned correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The generators are just a method to increase a time to development.  You can use them if it helps you or do not use them if you don't like them.

You [can create your own generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) if you think that it wull improve your development process.

Answer (score 0):

The generators are great to see the pattern. I am finding that as I learn more about the structure of a rails app the more I can choose what I want to do for each situation. For example I am finding that generating the models is just the way to go because of the the bits that are created (and versioned as d11wtq mentions). Then once I have the basics model to work with I can generate scaffold and use that a as a starting point for more hacking and changing.

I am looking into writing my own generators for one of the systems that has a lot of forms and at least that way I can avoid a lot of repetitive work - at least I hope so.

Hope that helps